# Spring Boot Mustache doesn't render UTF-8 correctly

Tags: utf-8, spring-boot, mustache

According to the official document, strings are encoded using UTF-8 by default. I investigated the auto-configed MustacheViewResolver and MustacheResourceTemplateLoader, both do have the charset property set to "UTF-8", but when i add a chinese word "中文", it doesn't display properly.

Does anybody know the solution? Thanks in advance.

Here is the pom.xml ( merely the official example ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-web-mustache</artifactId>
    <name>spring-boot-sample-web-mustache</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the code:

```
//main class
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleWebMustacheApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebMustacheApplication.class, args);
    }

}

//controller
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", this.message);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

and the template, with the chinese word "中文" in it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        Date: {{time.date}}
    <br>
    Time: {{time.time}}
    <br>
    Message: {{message}}中文
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me [setting servlet encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266913/springboot-response-charset-errors/62826669#62826669) worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this issue by upgrading to the latest version of spring boot.

Simply update the pom.xml to modify the version number:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

1.2.5 is the latest stable version (as of this writing).