# MockMvc: changing default character encoding of MockHttpServletResponse from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding, mockmvc

While writing Spring Itegration Tests I had the problem that MockMvc ignored my

```
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
```

setting, and returned ISO-8859-1 with bad looking umlaut.

What is the best way to set default encoding of MockMvc to UTF-8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I read that in spring boot the following setting would help.

```
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

In my case, where the setup is a bit special, **it did not**.

What **does work** for my setup is adding a filter to the MockMvc setup.

```
@Before
  public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
        .addFilter((request, response, chain) -> {
          response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // this is crucial
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }, "/*")
        .build();
  }
```

Hope it helps someone and saves some hours of try and error.

Comment: i'm having the same problem and noticed that the default MockMvc doesn't seem to honor the `spring.http.encoding.force=true`, ie. it's missing the `CharacterEncodingFilter`

Comment: Using the `spring.http.encoding.xxx` only works when using  `@SpringBootTest` but not with `@WebMvcTest`.

The latter only works when also adding `@Import(HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: None of this worked for me. MockMvc can be super frustrating because of things like this.

Comment: You just saved me from an imminent encoding hell, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

I got the idea from this SO Question: [SpringBoot response charset errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266913/springboot-response-charset-errors)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (Spring Framework 5.3.18):

```
MockMvcBuilders.defaultResponseCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

For example:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                   .standaloneSetup(controller)
                   .defaultResponseCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                 .build();
```