# English to Spanish translation not working in JSP file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, application.properties, spring-messaging

I am using this code to read property

```
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="training" class="form-check-label mt-30">                           
                               <form:checkbox id="training" path="isTraining" class="form-check-input"/><em><spring:message code="sol.settings.training.label"/></em>
                            </label>
                            <input type="button" class="bbtn bbtn-secondary pull-right mt-30" onclick="window.location='/sol/list/page/redirectToSolutionView.htm?filterId=MYITS&showAlert=false&searchText='" 
                            title="Cancel Solution"                     
                             value="<spring:message code='create.sol.page.cancelsol'/>"
                            
                            
                            />
                        </div>
```

The english translation works fine but for Spanish the data is not coming fine , it should come as create.sol.page.cancelsol = Cancelar solución
but here instead of solución it comes as "Cancelar soluci�n".
Why there is a question mark here?

Comment: I believe you mean Spanish?

Comment: @QBrute yes , really sorry it's spanish. But ya issue is same for French & SPanish.

Comment: The character encoding is not defined in the JSP. How would you know which character encoding is use to output the value?

Comment: @RomanC I didnt get that , however in the starting of the JSP I've added. <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: Don't post the code in comments. Instead edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a response configuration issue. The page is providing a response with content encoding different than UTF-8 (say, ISO-8859-1). This will make the symbols for accented characters such as "ñ", "ç" to appear as possibly unavailable symbols in the ISO-8859-1 encoding, making it to appear as the question mark.

I believe this article [SpringBoot response charset errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266913/springboot-response-charset-errors) will be of help to you: it explains how to configure springboot servlets to force a specific charset encoding for responses.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this link talks about the issue of JSON response coming from the API . In my case , the issue is connected with the JSP translation in SPanish. And reading data from the app.property. Can u please help me with that.

Comment: Let's go primitive here:  if you do a curl against your url, what is the content of the response headers? In my local example (that doesn't use springboot, BTW)
**curl -v http://localhost:8380/is_svc/whatever**

if the response you receive by hitting your application has a different charset than utf-8, you are in trouble.
...
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8**
< Content-Language: en

The article says how to configure springboot to provide responses in specific format.

Also, if this is a typical jsp, what is the main header in the code example you have shown?